# Set base URL/URI on Spring's RestTemplate in Spring 5.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring 5's `RestTemplate` in a Spring Boot 2 app, and trying to set a base URL/URI on it, so that I don't have to prepend each request with it. This will also allow me to set this value based on a property.

Previous versions of `ReleaseTemplate` let you set the base url through the constructor (e.g. `new ReleaseTemplate(baseUrl)`). But this is no longer the case.

I see that the `DefaultUriTemplateHandler` class has a `setBaseUrl()` that it inherits from the `AbstractUriTemplateHandler` interface, but that class has since been deprecated. The suggested replacement class `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` does not have any such methods.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following:-

```
String BASE_URI_TEMPLATE = "http://localhost:8080";

DefaultUriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(BASE_URI_TEMPLATE);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(uriBuilderFactory);
restTemplate.getForObject("/test", String.class); // like you may have used earlier
```

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic. The part I was missing was the method `RestTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler()`, that was the key. Also, it's worth pointing out to others that you cannot use this with the `RestTemplate` methods that require a `URI` object, as it will not have the full path.